# In Hadoop, if you want to keep the values from each key-value pair into an Array, why are all the elements that you add the same?

Tags: java, arraylist, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to store the values from the key-value pairs that the Map function gets and use them further. Given the following input:

```
Hello hadoop goodbye hadoop
Hello world goodbye world
Hello thinker goodbye thinker
```

An the following code:

**Note** - the map is the simple WordCount example

```
public class Inception extends Configured implements Tool{

public Path workingPath;

 public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

     // initialising the arrays that contain the values and the keys
    public ArrayList<LongWritable> keyBuff = new ArrayList<LongWritable>();
    public ArrayList<Text> valueBuff = new ArrayList<Text>();


    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);

        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
            context.write(word, one);
            System.out.println(word + " / " + one);
        }
    }   

    public void innerMap(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            // adding the value to the bufferr
        valueBuff.add(value);
        System.out.println("ArrayList addValue -> " + value);
        for (Text v : valueBuff){
            System.out.println("ArrayList containedValue -> " + value);
        }

        keyBuff.add(key);

        }   

    public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        setup(context);

        // going over the key-value pairs and storing them into the arrays
        while(context.nextKeyValue()){
            innerMap(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
        }


        Iterator itrv = valueBuff.iterator();
        Iterator itrk = keyBuff.iterator();
        while(itrv.hasNext()){
            LongWritable nextk = (LongWritable) itrk.next();
            Text nextv = (Text) itrv.next();
            System.out.println("Value iterator -> " + nextv);
            System.out.println("Key iterator -> " + nextk);

            // iterating over the values and running the map on them.

            map(nextk, nextv, context);
        }

        cleanup(context);
    }
 }

 public int run(String[] args) throws Exception { ... }

 public static void main (..) { ... }
```

Ok, now the log output:

**stdout logs**

```
ArrayList addValue -> Hello hadoop goodbye hadoop
ArrayList containedValue -> Hello hadoop goodbye hadoop
ArrayList addValue -> Hello world goodbye world
ArrayList containedValue -> Hello world goodbye world
ArrayList containedValue -> Hello world goodbye world
ArrayList addValue -> Hello thinker goodbye thinker
ArrayList containedValue -> Hello thinker goodbye thinker
ArrayList containedValue -> Hello thinker goodbye thinker
ArrayList containedValue -> Hello thinker goodbye thinker
Value iterator -> Hello thinker goodbye thinker
Key iterator -> 84
Hello / 1
thinker / 1
goodbye / 1
thinker / 1
Value iterator -> Hello thinker goodbye thinker
Key iterator -> 84
Hello / 1
thinker / 1
goodbye / 1
thinker / 1
Value iterator -> Hello thinker goodbye thinker
Key iterator -> 84
Hello / 1
thinker / 1
goodbye / 1
thinker / 1
```

So what you can notice is, that every time i add a new value to the ArrayList valueBuff, all the values in the list gets overwritten. Does anybody know why this is going on an why the values are not added properly in the Array?

Comment: The code is not at all readable, at least you could have removed the dead code :(

Comment: Updated the code. Removed, everything except the Map and the things that i want to do. Sorry for that, you're right i should have not posted all of it.

Answer (score 2):

[TextInputFormat](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/TextInputFormat.java) uses a [LineRecordReader](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/LineRecordReader.java). When Context#nextKeyValue is called then LineRecordReader#nextKeyValue is called.

In the LineRecordReader the same key and value objects are used in each call to the nextKeyValue method, only their contents are changed. A copy of the object has to be made in the user code if the key and value data should be hold.

This makes sense for optimization, if a new key and value object is created for every record then the system will go OOM easily.